# Как программно кликнуть по динамическому radio-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Всем привет!

Имеется такой код на странице:

```
<ul class="c-order__payment payment-details-list"><li class="noneactive">
    <label class="noneactive">
        <input type="radio" name="payment" rel="" value="4">Наличные (курьеру)  </label>
    <span class="icon-payment-4"></span>
    <span class="rate-payment"></span>
</li><li class="noneactive">
    <label class="noneactive">
        <input type="radio" name="payment" rel="" value="2">Яндекс.Деньги   </label>
    <span class="icon-payment-2"></span>
    <span class="rate-payment"></span>
</li></ul>
```

Код генериться после загрузки страницы. Как программно кликнуть по первому радио батону, после того как код сгенериться?
Пробовал так, не кликается:

```
setTimeout(ClickPayment, 2000);     


  function ClickPayment() {         
        $(".rate-payment:first").click();               
   }
```

Пробовал так:

```
setTimeout (ClickPayment, 1000);        

  function ClickPayment() {
     $(".rate-payment:first").closest(".noneactive").find("input[type=radio]").click();
  //$(".rate-payment:first").closest(".noneactive").find("input[type=radio]").attr('checked',true);
    alert ("test");
}
```

Не кликается. Пробовал закоментированный вариант не чекается.

Теперь попробовал так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span.deliveryName:first').click();
  setTimeout(ClickPayment, 1000);
  
  $("#container").append(
  `
  <div class="noneactive">div
  <input type="radio"/>
  <span class="rate-payment">span</span>
  </div>
  `
  );
});

function ClickPayment() {
  var item = $(".rate-payment:first").closest(".noneactive").find("input[type=radio]");
  console.log("ClickPayment: count =", item.length);
  item[0].click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Вот так сработало. ответ в консоли: ClickPayment: count = 1.
Так выглядит внутри Item:

```
r.fn.init(1)
0: input
length: 1
prevObject: r.fn.init [li.noneactive, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Создайте **работающий** пример, воспроизводящий проблему, которую Вы пытаетсь решить. Ваш пример воспроизводит только ошибку отсутствия в нем jQuery.

Comment: Igor,  я  вот честно не понимаю как сделать код работающим здесь, я вставил все ссылки со страницы проекта, но ошибка все равно остается.

Comment: Я поправил Ваш пример. Измените его так, чтобы он воспроизводил поведение, которое Вы хотите исправить.

Comment: Igor, спасисбо, красиво! Так должно работать. Но у меня клика не происходит  - еще раз проверил, хотя в консоли выводится то же. Насколько я понимаю, метод click() не совсем эквивалентен клику мышкой. В этом, видимо, и проблема. Клик видимо происходит. Однако  клик в моем проекте должен по идее запустить какой-то скрипт, который ставит красивый значек в радиокнопку, но это скрипт почему то не запускается, т.к. не происходит событие on click, видимо проблема в этом - в событии. Видел много ответов на эту тему, нужно проштудировать, но возможно и вы что-то быстрее подскажете.

Comment: Попробуйте `item[0].click();`

Comment: Igor, Bingo! Сработало, и вот почему: r.fn.init(1)
0: input
length: 1
prevObject: r.fn.init [li.noneactive, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
__proto__: Object(0)

Comment: Поздравляю! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неважно, динамическая это кнопка или нет. Главное, чтобы она существовала в момент  вызова функции.

```js
setTimeout(ClickPayment, 1000);

function ClickPayment() {
  $(".rate-payment:first").closest(".noneactive").find("input[type=radio]").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="c-order__payment payment-details-list">
  <li class="noneactive">
    <label class="noneactive">
        <input type="radio" name="payment" rel="" value="4">Наличные (курьеру)  </label>
    <span class="icon-payment-4"></span>
    <span class="rate-payment"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="noneactive">
    <label class="noneactive">
        <input type="radio" name="payment" rel="" value="2">Яндекс.Деньги   </label>
    <span class="icon-payment-2"></span>
    <span class="rate-payment"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

> Например, так:
>
> ```
> $('input').on('mouseover', function () { 
>   alert(JSON.stringify(
>       $(".rate-payment:first").closest(".noneactive").find("input[type=radio]").ClassName
>   ));
>   alert(JSON.stringify($("span.rate-payment:first").className)); 
> });
> ```

Язык Javascript - регистрозависимый. В нем `ClassName` и `className` - разные вещи. Но это в данном случае - не главное. У объекта, который возвращается функцией `$(...)`, нет ни свойства `ClassName`, ни свойства `className`.

```
console.log(
  $(".rate-payment:first").closest(".noneactive").find("input[type=radio]").attr("class")
);
console.log($("span.rate-payment:first").attr("class"));
```

---

> как можно "прозвонить" элемент

```
console.log($("span.rate-payment:first").length > 0? "exists" : "does not exist");
```

---

```
setTimeout (ClickPayment, 1000);        

function ClickPayment() {
  var item = $(".rate-payment:first").closest(".noneactive").find("input[type=radio]");
  console.log("ClickPayment: count =", item.length);
  item.click();
}
```

Что в консоли?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97589/discussion-on-answer-by-igor------radio-inpu).

Comment: @Sturmer Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса - как это сделано в моем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Может проще изначально его (radio button) подсовывать чекнутым? `<input type="radio" name="payment" rel="" value="4" checked>`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let content = '<ul class="c-order__payment payment-details-list"><li class="noneactive"><label class="noneactive"><input type="radio" name="payment" rel="" value="4" checked />Наличные (курьеру)</label><span class="icon-payment-4"></span><span class="rate-payment"></span></li><li class="noneactive"><label class="noneactive"><input type="radio" name="payment" rel="" value="2" />Яндекс.Деньги</label><span class="icon-payment-2"></span><span class="rate-payment"></span></li></ul>';
  $('body').append(content);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```